# Building a forms system using DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, specification-pattern

i'm building a form managment system, thats is, the system will contain many forms, will save them, and perform logic on them, I want to do it using the DDD approach.

I want to support easy form layout later on using ASP.NET MVC, so far i see the domain like this:

I'll have a base form entity, which should(for now) have a name, fields(and theire values) and validation logic.

My questions are:

1. How should i write the field valueobject using generics? i cant seem to figure it out..
2. Should i encapsulate the validation logic inside the form or do it using the specification pattern?

Answer (score 2):

> How should i write the field valueobject using generics? i cant seem to figure it out.

Too vague question. Specify your context a bit - what kind of value objects you are trying to define, why exactly you need generics etc.

> Should i encapsulate the validation logic inside the form or do it using the specification pattern?

Validation logic goes where [it has to go](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/02/15/validation-in-a-ddd-world.aspx). Domain validation logic should be encapsulated in specs, but that's not mandatory. Main thing - you should be able to figure out and understand applied validation when looking at source code of domain object class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your vague descriptions, dealing with forms is a problem that is inherently *not* well suited to DDD. What kind of an object model can you build from a flat list of options?

Of course you will need validation logic that is specific to the form in use, but simple OO Design will get you far enough here, I don't see where DDD will buy you something.

As a side note, check out Document Databases, they might be better suited for your task than a sophisticated domain model stored in an ObjectDb or a relational database.